# Using the integral function within a delay differential equation

Tags: r, differential-equations, dde

I am trying to encode in R, a delay differential equation model similar to the one in 
'An Invulnerable Age Class and Stability in Delay-Differential Parasitoid-Host Models Author(s): W. W. Murdoch, R. M. Nisbet, S. P. Blythe, W. S. C. Gurney and J. D. Reeve Source: The American Naturalist, Vol. 129, No. 2 (Feb., 1987), pp. 263-282'

Here is the model;

```
dU(t)/dt=r*A(t)-a*U*P(t)-Du(t)

dA(t)/dt=Mu(t)-Da(t)

dJ(t)/dt=a*U*P(t)-Mj(t)-Dj(t)

(dP(t)/dt=Mj(t)-Dp(t)

Mu(t)=E(t-T1)exp{-∫-(t-T1)^t[aP(x)+Du]dx}

Mj(t)= a*U*P(t-T2)exp(-DjT2)
```

I am having difficulty getting the integral portion of the code to work alongside the dde history function.

```
library(deSolve)
## Parameters
parameters <- c(r = 0.25, a = 0.01, Dl = 1, DN = 0.3, Dj= 0.5, DP = 0.5, tau = 2, Chi = 3)
init <- c(L= 5, N = 20,J= 10, P = 2, ML = 0, MH = 0)
time <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)

## Delayed DE
PreyPredLag <- function(times, y, parms){
  L<- y['L'] # # nymph prey
  N <- y['N']  #N <- init['N'] adult prey
  J <- y['J'] # juvenile parasitoid
  P <- y['P'] #P <- init['P'] # adult predator
  ML<- y['ML'] # maturing nymph prey
  MJ<- y['MJ'] # maturing juvenile predator

  r <- parms['r'] #growth rate prey
  a <- parms['a'] #attack rate predator
  Dl<- parms['Dl'] #mortality nymph prey
  DN<- parms ['DN'] # Death adult prey
  Dj<- parms ['Dj'] # Death juvenile parasitoid
  DP<- parms ['DP'] # death adult parasitoid
  tau <- parms['tau'] #time lag prey
  chi<- parms['chi'] # time lag parasitoid

  # History function
  tlag <- times - tau
  #tlag <- time - tau #different result
  if (tlag < 0)
    ylag <- y
  #ylag <- init
  else
    ylag <- lagvalue(tlag)

  # dede
  dL <- (r*N)- ML- (a*L*P)-(Dl*L)
  dN <- ML- (DN*N)
  DJ<- (a*L*P) - MJ- (Dj*J)
  dP <- MJ - (DP*P)
  ML <- ylag[1]*exp(integrate(pdeath<-function(x){(a*P*x+Dl)*x},lower = 0,upper=2))
  MJ<- ylag[3]*exp(-Dj*2)

  return(list(c(dL,dN,DJ, dP), lag = ylag))
}

dederesult <- dede(func = PreyPredLag, parms = parameters, y = init, times = time)
```

My current error is

> "Error in exp(integrate(pdeath <- function(x) { :    non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Although note I haven't encoded the `a*N*P(t-t2)` in the presented code

Comment: You have a `Chi` in `parameters` and a `chi` in the function, although it does not seem to be used anywhere

Comment: The `pdeath<-` in your `integrate` function does not look right - you would not normally assign a variable inside a list of function arguments

Comment: The error states a problem with `integrate`. If you read the `help(integrate)` page under `value` you will note that it returns not a single value but a `list` with several entries. As such you should use `integrate(...)$value` to correct the error. At which point you will get a new error, as your function has more parameters than derivatives.

Comment: Note that it is not a problem to assign a value within a function call using the `<-` operator as @AndrewGustar suggested. However it is not recommended as it makes it can often make code harder to read. In this case you are not actually using the assigned `pdeath` to anything, so you could leave this out entirely and just use `integrate(function(x) ....,  0, 2)$value`.

Comment: Hi both, really helpful comments thanks. Writing the ML state of the DDE  ```` ML <- ylag[1]*exp(integrate(function(x){(a*P*x+Dl)$value*x},lower = 0,upper=2))```` returns Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: chi is a parameter I wanted to use for a second lag value for the MJ equation. As you can see from the equation I am trying to replicate, instead of ylag[3] on the MJ state it should actually be the value of a*L*P two time steps prior, which is another question I need to work on

Comment: for formatting code in comments check the help in the lower right of comment while writing a comment. For `integrate` the correct format is `integrate(function(x) ( a * P * x + Dl) * x, 0, 2)$value` (note that i take the value of the result, not the value of the function within integrate).  I use `...` to indicate extra arguments (`function(x) ... , 0, 2 = function(x) (a * P * x + Dl) * x, 0, 2`). However note that a new error is produced as `init` contains `ML` and `MH`, but the function does not return values for `DML` and `DMH`.

Comment: Is the integration correctly formulated? Is `P` constant in the original definition of the integral? If yes, did you try to carry out the then trivial integration by hand and just insert the value of the integral? If no, what is the connection of `x` and `t`, and does the integral depend in other ways on the current time `t`?